# IIS - what is the physical file that has Username/Password of directory's Basic HTTP Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis, basic-authentication

I have a directory with Basic HTTP Authentication. I want to know the file where the username and password are stored.

I search a lot and read tons of articles but I can't find the real answer.
In Apache for example, it's stored in .htpasswd

Is it the same concept in IIS? meaning it's saved in a physical file like web.config or any other file type?

Comment: Domain accounts have credentials stored on domain controllers. Local accounts are stored by Windows in a secure place. Microsoft never uses password files for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic authentication is kind of clear context user credential authentication. It use both local account and domain account without kerberos ticket and encryption.

Besides, it is not stored in  IIS config file but operating system keep it. It is said that the file in system32/config store the user credential. But the file is encrypted so we can't open it easily.